# Simple limit proof!!

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\lim\ sup |s_n| = 0$ iif $\lim s_n = 0$.

Proof.$\leftarrow$.

Assume that $\lim s_n = 0$. Then, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N \ s.t\ n>N \rightarrow \left| s_n - 0 \right| < \epsilon$. This implies that $\left| s_n \right| < \epsilon \rightarrow \big|| s_n| - 0 \big|<\epsilon$. So $\lim |s_n| = \lim\ sup|s_n| = 0$.

Proof.$\rightarrow$.
Go backward.

Is this ok?

Comment: It looks fine to me.